# Dealing with different data frequencies on FB-Prophet

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I'm currently working on a forecasting project with FB-Prophet (I use python code). The data on which I want to make forecasts is weekly, I also have another time series that could be useful as an additional regressor but for this one, the past data is quarterly and the future values are only yearly. What would be the best solution to make the forecast using this additional time series?

My current idea is to linearly interpolate the additional data to get weekly data. But I think changing yearly data to weekly with this method is maybe too much. Does someone know a better solution?

Thank you for any future answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what kind of data you're gathering at a quarterly/annual level. How often does it change? If you're looking at the number of Republicans vs. Democrats in Congress, you can safely use interpolation or last-observation-carried-forward, even though the numbers can vary within a year. If you're looking at something like the closing price of the S&P 500, you are asking too much of your data to break annual numbers down to weekly.